# Saving for loop output into txt

Tags: python, for-loop, save

Im stuck in saving this for loop results, I've searched in stack all kind to save output of the for loop but I did come a the right solution. My code is:

```
doc = sys.argv[1]
target = sys.argv[2]
fene = int(sys.argv[3])

a = open(file)
text = a.read() 
a.close()

tokens = text.split()
keyword = re.compile(target, re.IGNORECASE)

for index in range( len(tokens) ):
    if keyword.match( tokens[index] ):
        start = max(0, index-window)
        finish = min(len(tokens), index+window+1)
        lhs = " ".join( tokens[start:index] )
        rhs = " ".join( tokens[index+1:finish] )
        print("%s \t \t %s \t \t %s" % (lhs, tokens[index], rhs))
```

I tried 
`f =  open("output.txt", w)` then at the end(line print) i've added `f.write(lsm, tokens[index], rhs)` this did not work. Even bringing open() into for loop.
How too handle it?
UPDATE: output of for loop that I want in txt.
[image]

Comment: What means "did not work"? What is variable "lsm"? Show where you tried to add the writing code.

Comment: It looks like you're closing `a` right after opening it. You should only close a file after doing all your reads/writes. It will also help if you post your actual error message with the exact code that produced it.

Comment: It is just the left margin, this and rhs contains string that can be N. N is given in parameter when running code.

Comment: this code work well. let me update the output

Comment: My Question is how to save the output to txt file.

Comment: "print" function can take a parameter "file" to redirect output to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Michael answer explanation in comment. Thanks

```
saveme = open('output.txt', 'w') 
for index in range( len(tokens) ):
    if keyword.match( tokens[index] ):
        start = max(0, index-window)
        finish = min(len(tokens), index+window+1)
        lhs = " ".join( tokens[start:index] )
        rhs = " ".join( tokens[index+1:finish] )
        print("%s \t \t %s \t \t %s" % (lhs, tokens[index], rhs), file=saveme)
saveme.close()
```